# How to keep DRY while creating common models in Django?

Tags: python, django, dry

For example I have 2 main models in my django app:

```
class Employee(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)

class Client(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=50)
```

Abstract base class for phones:

```
class Phone(Model):
    number = CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Inherited separate classes for Employee and for Client:

```
class EmployeePhone(Phone):
    employee = ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='employee_phones')

class ClientPhone(Phone):
    client = ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='client_phones')
```

It works but I don't like it, I would prefer to keep just one Phone model instead of 3. I know I could use Generic-Models but unfortunately that's not longer an option, because my app is actually REST-API and it seems to be impossible to create Generic-Object while creating Parent-Object. So is there any solution to keep things clean and DRY ?

Comment: I don't think that humidity issues are on-topic on SO. ;-) But seriously: please be more specific on where you are seeing issues and what a better solution would be like in your opinion.

Comment: I thought I made a clear point: "So is there any solution to keep things clean and DRY ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers present good ideas how you can normalise the database, but if you'd like to keep the schema the same and just avoid repeating the same thing in the code, maybe a [custom field subclass](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass) is what you're after?

Example:

```
# fields.py
class PhoneField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 50)
        ...
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

# models.py
class Employee(models.Model):
    phone = PhoneField()
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted, but it's gonna be useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping 1 Phone class and linking Employee and Customer to Phone via a Foreign Key and removing the abstract :).

Answer (score 0):

How about moving `EmployeePhone` (`ClientPhone`) as a ManyToManyField in `Employee` (`Client`) model related to `Phone` model?

```
class Employee(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    phones = ManyToManyField(Phone, ...)
```